# Show git pull graph in other situations

Tags: git

After `git pull`, a really nice summary graphic (e.g. below) is produced showing what files have changes and roughly how much.
  Is there a way to produce this graphic for a general comparison (i.e. between tags, or commits)?

Check the sample image below :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is:

```
git diff --stat SHA1 SHA2
```

this will display exactly the same thing as `git pull`. You have to specify the commmits you want to compare.

You can also use all other means of specifing other commits, such as:

```
git diff --stat HEAD^ HEAD
```

Or compare branches:

```
git diff --stat master develop
```